# PHPMailer SMTP connection timeout

Tags: wordpress, smtp, phpmailer

I've recently moved a Wordpress site from one server to another and I can no longer send mail via SMTP.

There is clearly somesort of network/resolver/credentials problem and I'm trying to debug it, but I've encountered some really unusual behaviour.

I'm looking at the `connect` method of the `SMTP` class. If I just try the code as it stands, then the line

```
$this->smtp_conn = @stream_socket_client(
            $host . ":" . $port,
            $errno,
            $errstr,
            $timeout,
            STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT,
            $socket_context
        );
```

causes a timeout. However if I add my own member variable eg `protected $myvariable;` and change the above code to assign the stream socket to `$myvariable` rather than `smtp_conn`, there is no time out.
If I check the unaltered code using `var_dump` on `$this->smtp_conn` just before trying to open the connection, it is NULL.

I've can't see any other code in PHPMailer which would effect the member variable `$smtp_conn` and I can't see how changing the name of a variable could stop the timeout.

Can anyone help me to debug this further.

================= EDIT =====================

I've discovered the assignment of `$this->smtp_conn` to the result of `stream_socket_client` causes the `get_lines` method to execute directly. That is, if I place an `exit` command directly after the assignment of `$this->smtp_conn = stream_socket_client`, the code in `get_lines` still runs.

Comment: It's not the assignment to a variable that's timing out, it's the `stream_socket_client` call which happens first. I'd check through the troubleshooting guide and eliminate network issues first.

Comment: That's the really odd thing, it is the assignment which is timing out! If I create and assign a different variable to the result of stream_socket_client, then the timeout doesn't happen.